# Python - Break String into nested dictionary keys

Tags: python

I have a string: `candidate__name__first_name`. I want to convert it into a nested dictionary of the form:

```
{ 
  candidate: {
    name: {
      first_name: 'MyName'
    }
  }
}
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Your input has no `MyName`, therefore it would be difficult for it to end up in the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
recursive_key = 'candidate__name__first_name'
value = 'MyName'
for key in reversed(recursive_key.split('__')):
    value = {key: value}
print(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sth. like this:

```
tokens = 'candidate__name__first_name'.split('__')
final_d = d = {}
for token in tokens[:-1]:
    d[token] = {}
    d = d[token]
d[tokens[-1]] = 'MyName'

final_d
# {'candidate': {'name': {'first_name': 'MyName'}}}
```